# How Keras Lambda works

Tags: python, keras

I am struggling to understand the way that the Lambda layers are working in keras. For example, I have the following example:

```
add_layer = Lambda(lambda x:x[0]+x[1], output_shape=lambda x:x[0])
```

Given my input x what exactly I am expecting from the output layer of the `Labmda`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Lambda` layer works similar to Python lambda function. But instead of a function, it returns a `Layer` object that performs whatever passed in that lambda function.

You generally use the lambda layer as follows. Which gives out as the result of performing whatever passed in as the Lambda function.

`out = add_layer(<some_input>)`

For example in the function above you need to pass in a list of two items (denoted by `x[0]` and `x[1]`. And the lambda layer would perform an element-wise add operation on those two tensors.

You can use this lambda layer in a model as follows. Note that the two inputs `inp1` and `inp2` need to be **broadcastable** (does not necessarily need to have the same shape - e.g. (10, 5) and (10, 1) would still work).

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

inp1 = layers.Input(shape=(5))
inp2 = layers.Input(shape=(1))
add_layer = layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[0]+x[1], output_shape=lambda x:x[0])
out = add_layer([inp1, inp2])
model = models.Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=out)
model.summary()
```

Then you would use this layer as follows.

```
x1 = np.ones(shape=(10, 5))*1.0
x2 = np.ones(shape=(10, 1))*2.0
print(model.predict([x1, x2]))
```

Which will return

```
[[3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]]
```

**PS**: I would leave the `output_shape` argument out because Keras will automatically infer the shape in this case (it's a simple element wise add). Because otherwise what would happen is that, if you pass

```
inp1 = layers.Input(shape=(1))
inp2 = layers.Input(shape=(5))
```

The output would have the wrong shape. Because it is always getting the shape of the first tensor as the shape. However in this case the shape would be the shape of the second tensor.

Comment: But how can I perform the addition in the case that the input does not have the same size?

Comment: For example, if you have an input of size `(10, 5)` and `(10,1)`, the second input will be repeatedly added to each column of the first one. This is essentially coming from the idea of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Then still there is a need for some correspondence, cannot be of different dimension for example, right?

Comment: Yes you need some correspondence. For example (10,5) & (10,5) works / (10,5) & (10, 1) works / (10,5) (1,1) works / (10,5) & (10,3) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here your lambda layer is doing the addition of 2 inputs.
You would typically use it as:

```py
add_layer = Lambda(lambda x:x[0]+x[1])
input_1 = Input(input_1_shape)
input_2 = Input(input_2_shape)
output = add_layer([input_1, input_2])
```

This will compute the addition between the 2 tensors.

Of course this is a toy example, and if you really want the addition between 2 tensors, you can use the `Add` layer.

Another thing, you don't need to specify the output shape in most cases, except if you work with complex or integer tensors.